# Populating multiple textboxes with data at once

Tags: vb.net, textbox

I have a form containing 6 groupboxes, each groupbox containing 180 textboxes, along with two combobxes. On selecting a value from the first combobox, the second combobox gets filled with required data from a table. My requirement is that upon selecting a value from the second combobox, filtered data from the same table should fill the remaining textboxes. The code I am using is as follows:

```
    Private Sub ComboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox2.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim strConnection As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0; Data Source=c:\\users\\brisingr\\documents\\123\database.mdb"
    Dim objConnection As New OleDbConnection(strConnection)

    Dim strsql As String
    'strsql = "Select * from '" & ComboBox1.Text & "' where Style = '" & ComboBox2.Text & " '"
    Dim a As String
    Dim b As String
    Dim c As String
    Dim d As String
    a = "Select * from ["
    b = ComboBox1.Text
    c = "] where Style = ["
    d = ComboBox2.Text
    strsql = a & b & c & d & "]"
    Dim objCommand As New OleDbCommand(strsql, objConnection)

    Dim objDataAdapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(objCommand)
    Dim objDataTable As New DataTable("Buyers")
    objDataAdapter.Fill(objDataTable)

    objConnection.Close()
    objConnection.Dispose()
    objConnection = Nothing
    objCommand.Dispose()
    objCommand = Nothing
    objDataAdapter.Dispose()
    objDataAdapter = Nothing

    For i As Integer = 1 To 60
        Me.Controls("L1Ob" & i).Text = objDataTable.Rows(0)("Operation" & i)
    Next

End Sub
```

Here "Operation" & (i) refers to the field name of the database, which have been named like operation1, operation2 and so on...

This code does not seem to be working for me. Please help..

Comment: Me.Controls refers to controls directly contained by your form. If the TextBoxes are inside a groupBox you need to use the controls collection of that combobox

Comment: @Steve: So how do i do that? I am still learning vb.net...

Comment: And by the way, saying 'the code doesn't seem to be working' is really annoying. How we can help you if you don't tell us what is not working?

Comment: try with  `Me.YourGroupBoxName.Controls("L1Ob" & i).Text = objDataTable.Rows(0)("Operation" & i)`

Comment: @Steve: the textboxes are not populating... I keep getting the error "No value given for one or more required parameters." How am i to know which parameters have no value...???

Comment: So the error is not in the code that populates the textbox but in your sql command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we have many problems

```
Dim a As String
Dim b As String
Dim c As String
Dim d As String
a = "Select * from ["
b = ComboBox1.Text
c = "] where Style = ["
d = ComboBox2.Text
strsql = a & b & c & d & "]"
Dim objCommand As New OleDbCommand(strsql, objConnection)
```

First, you have square brackets around the value passed for the field `Style`.
And this is not a valid syntax. The Jet engine assumes that is a parameter. 
Actually, passing a parameter, is the right way to go.

```
a = "Select * from [" 
b = ComboBox1.Text
c = "] where Style = ?"
strsql = a & b & c
Dim objCommand As New OleDbCommand(strsql, objConnection)
objCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", ComboBox2.Text)
Dim objDataAdapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(objCommand)
Dim objDataTable As New DataTable("Buyers")
objDataAdapter.Fill(objDataTable)
```

The value for the field `Style` is passed with a parameter. This leaves the work to replace the placeholder (?) with the value taken from the combobox to the framework.
You could be sure that it knows better of to do that avoiding errors and sql injections.

This code is still weak. You should be absolutely sure that the contents of the first combobox1 could not be modified to contains malicious text instead of table names

Comment: What is @p1? because now i am getting an error that "No value given for one or more required parameters."

and as for the square brackets, I put them there as the backend is MS Access and for multi-word data search, like "I See you", a square bracket is the best solution that i know of... if you know some other solution, please, do help me out...

Comment: I make sure that the combobox1 text does not differ from the buyers name by having a table containing the list of tables, which is updated as a new a table is added through a query, and the value shown in the combobox1 is from the table with the list of tables.. If there is any other way of doing this, please tell me...

Comment: You need to see what is the exact command text that is sent to the database engine. Set a breakpoint just after the construction of strSql and let me see what is the exact text that gives the error

Comment: I am getting the following error after changing the codes as per your instructions- "Null reference exception was handled. Object reference not set to an instance of an object.", at the `code`Me.YourGroupBoxName.Controls("L1Ob" & i).Text = objDataTable.Rows(0)("Operation" & i)`code` ... I checked more than once with more than one values...

Comment: `YourGroupBoxName` is supposed to be your actual combobx. It is just an example name. Change with the groupbox name you really have in you app

Comment: yeah i did change that to the name i have assigned to my groupbox in the forms. but still i have the error.

Comment: The expression `("L1Ob" & i).Text` works only if you are sure that you have all the 60 controls and that they exist inside the GroupBox otherwise it is like writing `NULL.text = ....` and this gives the error.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion... I checked and corrected the error... i had named only 25 textboxes currently for testing and when i changed the code to i = 1 to 25, it worked perfectly... thanks a lot...

Comment: just one more thing... if i were to change the sql string "strsql" to something like:

`code`        "Select * from @p2 where style = ?"
`code`        objCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", ComboBox2.Text)
`code`        objCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", ComboBox1.Text)`code`

would it work the same as the string as it is working now?

Comment: No it is not possible to use parameters in place of the column or table name. These should be written down explicitely. Parameters could be used (in select queries) only to express values in your where clause